# "Out of Memory" error when using store procedures

Tags: c#, odbc, sybase-asa

I wrote some services for creating dbs, copying some records among dbs or tables etc, so many db operations. But im dealing with memory problems. One of them:

Im getting records with store procedures and filling in entity lists;

```
    public List<FpBatteryEntity> LoadFPBattery()
    {
        List<FpBatteryEntity> retVal = new List<FpBatteryEntity>();

        DataSet dataSet = _dataAccessProvider.ExecuteSPDataSet("sp_fp_battery", null);
        if (dataSet != null && dataSet.HasData())
        {
            DataTable requestsTable = dataSet.Tables[0];
            if (requestsTable != null && requestsTable.HasData())
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in requestsTable.Rows)
                {
                    FpBatteryEntity entity = new FpBatteryEntity()
                    {
                        Faceplate = row["tf_faceplate"],
                        Battery = row["tf_battery"]
                    };
                    retVal.Add(entity);
                }
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

Then for each entity in list, executing a new sp;

```
    public bool LoadFPBattery(List<FpBatteryEntity> entityList)
    {
        foreach (var entity in entityList)
        {
            DBParameterCollection parameters = new DBParameterCollection
            {
                new DBParameter("@faceplate", SqlDbType.VarChar, entity.Faceplate),
                new DBParameter("@battery", SqlDbType.VarChar, entity.Battery)
            };

            _dataAccessProvider.ExecuteSPNonQuery("sp_ins_fp_battery", parameters);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Unfortunately, I have more than 30 operations like that and also some of them are processing thousands of records.

Calling steps like that;

```
        .....

        List<MapColorEntity> mapColor = _dbRepository.LoadMapColor(marketId);
        if (!_otherDbRepository.LoadMapColor(mapColor))
            return false;

        List<AttributesEntity> attributes = _dbRepository.LoadOptionAttrib(marketId);
        if (!_otherDbRepository.LoadOptionAttrib(OptionAttributes))
            return false;

        List<FpBatteryEntity> fpBattery = _dbRepository.LoadFPBattery();
        if (!_otherDbRepository.DelFPBattery())
            return false;
        if (!_otherDbRepository.LoadFPBattery(fpBattery))
            return false;

        .....
```

After 5-6 step operations are corrupting with **"Out of Memory"** error. I have to make these all operations step by step. Just wondering that if you have a suggestion to make these operations more fruitful and smooth. How can i solve this memory problem? What happens in back?

Usages;

Windows 7 Operating System, 3Gb Usable Ram, Sybase ASE, Odbc Driver

Comment: Do you actually need to load every single row from every single one of those queries into memory at once?  Can you not stream the results so that you're only holding a fraction of them in memory at one time?  Also, don't use one DB context for your entire application; make a new one for each transaction you make; it will help lower your memory footprint.

Comment: @servy, streaming results maybe serves the purpose, I'll try it. But my code will be more complicated, will not?

Comment: Not dramatically, depending on what you're doing.  Use `IEnumerable` rather than `List` and turn the methods into iterator blocks (which honestly simplifies them, not complicates them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a [DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of a DataTable.  It looks like the way you're doing this there will be two copies of your data in memory.

Comment: thanks fr res, maybe DataReader will solve my problem but I have to use a dll that gives me "_dataAccessProvider.ExecuteSPDataSet". I dont know why but none of dll methods returns with DataReader :( Maybe I have more usable Ram than 3gb, above code will be executed correctly. I think the person that wrote the dll, have unlimited ram  or anything else :) Do you have any different idea? makes me functional

Comment: You could possibly remove the record from the DataTable once you've read it.